# preg_match with first instance

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab a word(s) between the word "in" and "with" inside of a string. The problem is that I have another instance of "with", it will extend the wildcard.

Here is an example:

```
$item   = 'This is a car in red with new tires and with a radio';
$pattern =  = '/in (.*) with/i';
preg_match($pattern, $item, $matches);
```

Returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "in red with new tires and with"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "red with new tires and"
}
```

What I would like $matches[1] to be is 'red'

Comment: You need lazy quantifier here - `$pattern =  = '/in (.*?) with/i';`, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/oL78A8).

Comment: Thanks.. that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern to:

```
$pattern  = '/in ([^\s]*)(.*) with/i';
// Array ( [0] => in red with new tires and with [1] => red [2] => with new tires and )
```

Where `([^\s]*)` means - take all symbols which are not `space`.